# Dash To Panel Extension breaks Lockscreen on Thinkpad T495

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

I started usign the "dash to panel" extension a while ago because I like the way it integrates the top bar and the favourite bar into a single one (like in windows) and how it displays multible opened windows for a single application. Also it gives me extra space on my display. Sadly, turning on the extension breaks the lockscreen after restarting the computer. With manually turning off and on the extension it works until the next shutdown and restart.

Whenever that glitch is present, it freezes the screen for a short time, then does something which looks like it wants to go to the login screen, but immediatly throws me back to the desktop. This happens with manual locking as well as automated (on suspend for example).

Does anybody out there have an idea why this is happening? Obviously disabling the extension can fix this permanently, however I'd like to keep using it. The computer is a Thinkpad T495 (Ryzen 5 3500U, 16 GB RAM, 512 GB NVMe SSD, integrated graphics). Thanks everybody for your input.

Comment: This may be related to your problem https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/1026

Comment: @kenn Thanks, that links was really useful. The solution was, according to the people posting there, do downgrade the Gnome Shell to .36.2-1ubuntu1 from 36.2. They recommend to wait for 36.3 to be released as my described bug seems to be acknowledged and fixed in the upcomming version. I will keep an eye out for that one. Thanks for all.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it is slightly different from yours. My Gnome shell kills and restarts itself when I try to lock the screen. The next time when I lock the screen it gets locked successfully. It actually happens on an alternate basis.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Following @kenn's comment, this is fixed by ugrading to Gnome 3.36.3, I've tested with Dash2P v38. seems to work.

I did `sudo apt upgrade` and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, hit <kbd>R</kbd> to restart the Shell.

If that does not work, reboot your machine too.

That's from the same issue posted by @kenn. Thanks man!